# Image text retrieval evaluation metric

Tags: deep-learning, information-retrieval, precision-recall, multimodal, image-text

I am currently working on text image retrieval where basically, given a test query, I should be able to retrieve all the related images.
For example- 'children playing in park', should retrieve all relevant images.
I do know the evaluation metric to use for this is Precision@k. I also understand what it is.

However, i don't know how to find it since i don't have associated labels on what images are relevant for what input query.
I am using Flickr30K dataset.

Comment: In such cases you need to annotate the relevance labels to build ur gound-truth

Comment: Yeah, i figured. I feel there must be a prebuilt ground label since its a very popular dataset and domain. I see a lot of papers on the same. However I couldn't find any ground truth labels anywhere online.